# AcceptThread is not returning to Activity on bluetooth file transfer app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, file-transfer

I am making a `Bluetooth` based file transfer app and I am not sure how to work with Threads here.

When I start listening for incomming connections on the Server part of the app works fine but the thread I use to do this task and not block the UI is not returning to the Main Activity after being invoked on it. Here is part of the code:

```
 public class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        private BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        public BluetoothSocket mmBlueToothSocket;
        private final BluetoothAdapter mmBluetoothAdapter;  

        /*Accept incomming connections on the server*/
        public AcceptThread(BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter){

            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            this.mmBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothAdapter;

            //works well
            try {
                this.mmServerSocket = mmBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(BluetoothConfig.mServiceName,BluetoothConfig.mUUID);            

            } catch (IOException e) {
                mmServerSocket = tmp;
                Log.d("AcceptThreadConstructorErr:", e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        public void run(){

            //while (true){         
                try {
                    mmBlueToothSocket = this.mmServerSocket.accept();
                    Log.d("AcceptThreadRun:", "mmServerSocket reached");
                } catch (IOException e) {               
                    Log.d("AcceptThreadRunErr:", e.getMessage());
                    //break;
                }
            //}      

  //If I call the ConnectedThread part of the code here it raises an  error so I am trying to call it from my Activity but is not returning there after executing the run part of this class        

        }//run  

}//AcceptThread class


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
public BluetoothSocket mmBlueToothSocket;

          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           //accept to listen for incomming connections
           AcceptThread acceptThread = new AcceptThread(bConfig.getBluetoothAdapter());
           acceptThread.start();

           //After the start execution this part is never reached!!
           connectedThread();

          }

          //Called from acceptThread once innitiated the connections listening in AcceptThread
          public void connectedThread(){

           socket = acceptThread.mmBlueToothSocket;

           if (socket == null){
               Log.d("acceptThread:", "socket Null in acceptThread");
           }               

           if (socket != null){

                try {       

                    ConnectedThread connected = new ConnectedThread(socket);
                    connected.start();  
                    Log.d("serverConnect", "connect.start() ok");

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("serverConnect:", e.getMessage());
                } 

           } 

       }//connectedThread

}//Activity
```

Can you please tell me, what component of the Thread implementation I am missing (maybe a `Handler`?), to be able to reach the `ConnectedThread` part and make it to work?. There doesn't seem to be an error, is just the Thread exiting and not returning to the caller activity.

Thanks

Comment: in what function is acceptThread.start() being called? you have put the calls in a static context?

Comment: @nandeesh, the call is being made on the activity, look at the last part of the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return to the Activity from the `AcceptThread` I used this into its run method

```
(this.mmActivity).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {             
              ((MainActivity)mmActivity).connectedThread();
            }
});
```

Where `connectedThread` method has been declared and implemented in the activity as the updated post show. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

eAs there is not all your code here we can't check it.

But I see something weird:

```
//accept to listen for incoming connections
       AcceptThread acceptThread = new AcceptThread(bConfig.getBluetoothAdapter());
       acceptThread.start();

       //This part is never reached!!!!
       Log.d("acceptThread:", "acceptThread.start() is executed");
```

This is called in your activity? Where in your activity?

**You would normally put it somewhere like in the onCreate() method.** This is not what you show. Otherwise your code should not even compile.

Indeed, I don't see any other reason, as the main purpose of a thread is to run "in parallel". So, immediately after  acceptThread.start(); is called, Log.d("acceptThread:", "acceptThread.start() is executed"); should be executed. And in the same time the content of the run method of your thread should be executed.

Besides, you should be able to start your ConnectedThread in your AcceptThread without problem.

So I guess Nandeesh is right.

Comment: I forgot to add the OnCreate part to work, have updated it accordingly. I also managed to call the connectedThread part of the code from the AcceptThread using runOnUiThread method, still I don't understand why I can't call it from inside the AcceptThread without an error.